# Can't create proper Tree Structure in table using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, tree-structure

I have been trying to make a "connecting line - tree structure" for a tournament bracket system.

However, it is more troubling than I thought. My goal is to have a line connecting the boxes such as http://gyazo.com/4ea425163a8f3e6901b464085421c449, but I do not want to use any images.

I figured it could be  done through borders or some other thing but I am unsure. My concept right now does not look too good, and I was wondering if anyone could offer some help on what I should try to go with.

http://jsfiddle.net/zet5uh7f/1/

```
#spacer {
    padding: 5px;
}
#connecter { 
     border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

I figured somehow I have to make this `border:left` on #connector move to the right, and add something on spacer to make it look normal. Is using a `border` something you  would recommend?

Comment: First of all, [`ID`'s are unique](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/), so don't use `ID`'s and you can use `<hr>` inside the `connecter` like this example - http://jsfiddle.net/o180en0j/

Comment: Show (in the question itself) HTML and CSS code you have tried, preferably a minimal case that illustrates the problem. Then explain clearly what is unsatisfactory in it.

Comment: now see my answer update its done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zet5uh7f/5/)

### [fullscreen jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zet5uh7f/5/embedded/result/)

#### solved using only css3  !

---

[image]
**html**

```
<div class="test">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Round 1</strong>

                </td>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Round 2</strong>

                </td>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Round 3</strong>

                </td>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Round 4</strong>

                </td>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Round 5</strong>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td rowspan="3"></td>
                <td rowspan="3" class="connecter connecter2"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td rowspan="7"></td>
                <td rowspan="7" class="connecter connecter3"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td rowspan="15"></td>
                <td rowspan="15" class="connecter connecter4"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td rowspan="3"></td>
                <td rowspan="3" class="connecter connecter2"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td rowspan="3"></td>
                <td rowspan="3" class="connecter connecter2"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td rowspan="7"></td>
                <td rowspan="7" class="connecter connecter3"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td rowspan="3"></td>
                <td rowspan="3" class="connecter connecter2"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1"></td>
                <td rowspan="1" class="connecter connecter1"></td>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="team"><span class="dash-back"> -----</span>Team<span class="dash-front"> -----</span> -----</span>
                </td>
                <td width="20" id="spacer"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
table {
            width: 60%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        td {
            border: 0px;
            position:relative;
        }
        #team {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            z-index:999;
            background:#fff;
        }
        .dash-front {
            position:absolute;
            content:"----------";
            letter-spacing: -2px;
            right:-18px;
            z-index:-999;
        }
        .dash-back {
            position: absolute;
            content: "----";
            letter-spacing: -3px;
            left: -15px;
            z-index: -999;
        }
        #spacer {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .connecter {
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            /*transform:translateX(18px) scaleY(1.65);*/
        }
        td.connecter1{
            transform-origin: center;
            transform:translateY(1px) translateX(18px) scaleY(2.05);
        }
        td.connecter2{
            transform-origin: center;
            transform:translateY(1px) translateX(18px) scaleY(1.34);
        }
        td.connecter3{
            transform-origin: center;
            transform:translateY(1px) translateX(18px) scaleY(1.15);
        }
        td.connecter4{
            transform-origin: center;
            transform:translateY(2px) translateX(18px) scaleY(1.07);
        }
        #connecter:after {
            /*content:"------";*/
            letter-spacing: -2px;
        }
        td:first-child .dash-back{display: none;}
        td:last-child .dash-front{display: none;}
```

Comment: This is great, but I am still confused on how to add the lines from the boxes like this http://gyazo.com/aa7e9b5f6263af26af223205f7147f28 As you can see, there are lines connecting from the middle of the two earlier boxes. My guess is realigning the table or more css...

Comment: that is also possible wait a little for it

Comment: Wow, this seemed to do it! I never really understood the transform code, but now that I can see how you did it, it makes sense.